# app crashes after restart

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm new to iphone development, and just to get a feel for it, I created a new view which has an alert popup on every load.

This works correctly, however when i shut the app down, then reopen it, the whole app crashes. The only thing I'm doing is showing an alert.

This is my code of the alert:

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle: @"Announcement"
                      message: @"This is really annoying just to make"
                      delegate: nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

I think I'm supposed to put `[alert release];` but Xcode keeps saying that `release` is unavailable.

Is the `[alert release]` the reason my app keeps crashing on exit/restart?

Thanks!

Edit: Heres the surrounding code where I call UIAlertView

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

//just testing alerts..this shows up after the first load only
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle: @"Announcement"
                      message: @"This is really annoying just to make"
                      delegate: nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];

}
```

Comment: `release` isn't needed with ARC. If your project was just started (not older then a few weeks) ARC was probably enabled by default. There has to be an other reason for the crash. What error do you get on crash? Also, try removing all the alert view code to see if that's causing it (I doubt it).

Comment: Where do you call the `[alert show]` method ? It might (but I doubt it) be a threading problem

Comment: i call [alert show] in the `(void) viewDidLoad` method. And I don't get an error; when i check the debug session it says `THREAD 1: SIGKILL` so I'm a bit confused

Comment: You need to show the code for your new view -- there's nothing in the code you posted that should cause a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`release` will be unavailable if you use ARC

Also, It is pretty unusual for a simple alert to cause a crash, as @rdelmar said in the comments, you really need to provide more info about your problem... One thing you could try though is to display your `UIAlertView` inside `viewDidAppear` instead of the `viewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score -3):

yes, you should supposed to put [alert release].  And to analyze the app crash, you should provide some information.

Comment: This is incorrect and will in no way trigger a crash on a fresh project. If worse comes to worse, then omitting a release in a non-ARC setup would trigger a leak. Such minimal leak (UIAlert) will hardly ever trigger a memory shortage even if the OP was using an ancient doorstopper (aka original iPhone).